# JAXB: How to make EntityHolder work with JSON request

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb

Create api call looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response createEntity(EntityHolder<Entity> entity){}
```

If send a xml request it works fine but in case of Json payload it throws

```
ERROR  - caught an UnrecognizedPropertyException in the REST layer
21:35:36,836 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "someProperty" (class com.sun.jersey.core.provider.EntityHolder), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties:
```

Looks like jackson is confusing `EntityHolder` with actual `Entity` class.

Comment: Yes it does. If you pay attention to the stack trace. jackson is considering `EntityHolder` as an actual `Entity` class.

Comment: Right. Which means jackson could not find `someProperty` of EntityHolder class. Instead of that jackson should have tried to find `someProperty` in `Entity` class. Isn't it?

Comment: Right. I see your point. My apologies and I will remove all my confusing comments.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I didn't find a good but a functional solution.

You can inject the Request with @Context and get the body content like this.

So, you can use jackson, gson or the implementation that you to prefer to unmarshall them.

That isn't the best solution, but it can help you.